# How to set a static IP on a virtualbox VM?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, virtual-machine, virtualbox

On Windows 10 i try to set up a ubuntu server VM with a static IP.

How can i accomplish this ? I heard that i have to use a bridge connection ?

I want the ip of my vm be accessible from my windows session.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require the guest to be accessible from the local LAN you will need to use the bridged adapter, thus allowing DHCP from the directly connected LAN. (you can take the DHCP address and statically assign it to the guest or do a DHCP reservation)

Another option is to setup a NATNetwork (VirtualBox/Preferences) setup Port Forwarding to allow your VirtualBox host (192.168.56.0/24) to forward tcp/udp to your static assigned guest IP 10.0.2.x/24

Host request
https://192.168.56.x:1234 will be forwarded to your unbuntu guest static IP of 10.0.2.x:443

External request will require routing tables on the remote computer to be added or windows 10 LAN default gateway will require static route for 192.168.56.x/24 via Windows 10 LAN IP, however your host firewall rules will have to configured.